# eBay API Additional Costs

Tags: xml, ebay-api

When listing/adding items via the eBay API, we have some additional costs that are not recognized by eBay but that we need to add to our item listing.  We don't want a buyer to win an auction for one price, and then go and find out that they would have to pay an extra $10 or so because of some extra fees we have to charge in relation to the item they purchased.  However, while we have attempted to send additional costs via the ShippingServiceAdditionalCost tag, eBay has ended up ignoring the extra costs we added.

1. Is there a way that we can submit additional fees (beyond shipping) for certain items to eBay via the API, and have them be added to the total final cost of the item?
2. Can we send multiple instances of an xml tag for one item to eBay and have them be calculated?  For example can we do two instances of 3.45 and 10.00?
3. Can we send customizable tags to eBay via the API that have additional costs that can be added to the final amount for the auctioned item?